# Why does Pandoc not include abstract when LaTeX is converted to plain text?

Tags: pandoc

I have a latex document (`example.tex`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
  This does not get exported.
\end{abstract}

But this is fine.

\end{document}
```

And want to export it to plain text:

```
pandoc --to=plain example.tex
```

However, only the body of the document gets exported, the abstract is excluded from the export.

How do I make `pandoc` export my abstract too?

*I believe that this is answered somewhere in the docs, but I just fail to find where for a relatively long time.*

Answer (score 3):

This is a fun question and goes deeply into the way pandoc represents documents. **tldr**: abstracts are treated as metadata, which are not included in plain output per default.

Here are the details: pandoc uses a simple document model which is built from the main text plus additional metadata like *title* and *author*. We can see this when running `pandoc -s -t gfm example.tex`, which will output a GitHub Flavored Markdown and include the metadata in a YAML block.

```markdown
---
abstract: |
  This does not get exported.
---

But this is fine.
```

The abstract is there, but in the YAML metadata. Whether and how the metadata is included in the output depends on the output format and the *template* that pandoc uses. Pandoc fills the template with data from the document. One can check the default template that's used by running `pandoc -D plain`, but there is some magic behind the scenes that adds special variables, so the output is only moderately instructive.

What's important for us is that we can use a custom template to include the abstract:

```
ABSTRACT
--------

  $abstract$

$body$
```

Then if we run pandoc with

```
pandoc -t plain --template=OUR-TEMPLATE.plain example.tex
```

we get what we want:

```
ABSTRACT
--------

  This does not get exported.


But this is fine.
```